# Как присвоить цвету RGB свой номер цифрой?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Сначала я делаю скриншот и записываю цвет пикселя в RGB

Код:

```
screen = ImageGrab.grab()
screen.save('case5.png','PNG')
im = Image.open('case5.png')
pix = im.load()
pix1 = pix[1570,328]
print(pix1)
```

В консоли я цвет в RGB :
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Мне нужно чтобы новая переменная NumberOfColor была равна 1 ,если цвет RGB(85,85,85) , если же нет , то 2 .

Хотел сделать так :

```
if pix1 == "(85 ,85 ,85)":
  NumberOfColor = 1 
else:
  NumberOfColor = 2
print(NumberOfColor)
```

Comment: Кавычки не нужны, видимо, это обычный кортеж с виду. Попробуйте if pix1 == (85 ,85 ,85):

Comment: @CrazyElf Моя глупая ошибка ...

Comment: micro optimization: `NumberOfColor = int(pix1 == (85, 85, 85)) + 1;`, if I'm not mistaken